# How many aircraft can airline put in hangar?

Tags: airline-operations, hangar

Another [question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/22296/aircraft-movement-in-and-out-of-hangar) talks about aircraft movement in and out of hangar.  Most hangar I see at commercial airport I see one aircraft per hangar.

This makes me wonder how many aircraft can be kept in the hangar depth-wise(ie nose-to-tail direction)? Is larger hangar common?

<sub>Note: please do not include special hangars such as those at Airbus or Boeing facility in main answer but side note about those are welcomed.</sub>

Comment: At general aviation airports it is quite common to have quite many (10+) airplanes in hangar, especially when gliders are included. Pushing them all in is kind a 3D tetris when trying to push one aircraft wing below other aircraft fuselage.
In some cases some gliders are winched up and stored suspended below the roof.

Comment: I think this is rather too broad for this site. Hangars will be built depending on the space available, resources available to build them and the purpose to which they are to be put. This will vary enormously around the world, and I doubt there's any sort of standard.

Comment: Related question: [What is the minimum distance between two civil airplanes parked in a hangar?](//aviation.stackexchange.com/q/19497)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many as possible. The number of aircraft will vary depending on the size, (wing) height above the ground, etc. Most commercial airliners put any number of aircraft as long as there is no problem of damage during movement.

For example, the following image shows one Boeing 747 Dreamlifter (N780BA) parked between two Airbus A380’s inside Lufthansa Technik’s Fankfurt hangar.

[image: Lufthansa Hangar]

Source: airlinereporter.com

The hangars are usually on the larger side because they are designed and constructed keeping the larger aircraft in mind. Then smaller aircraft will have little problem fitting into that. This image shows the floor plan for an aircraft hangar.

[image: Floor Plan]

Source: psp-architekten.de

Comment: A) That image is quite odd, seeing a Boeing between the two Airbus (I wonder if it was getting picked on ;).  B) Since the OP mentioned aircraft parked nose-to-tail, while you can only get 1 A380/747 in that hanger, you could get at least 9 C172s in there with _plenty_ of room to spare!

Answer (score 2):

There are no restrictions. You can put as many aircraft into a hangar as you can fit into it.

Some commercial hangars are neatly arranged.

[image: CommHangar]

Some are not as neatly arranged but efficiently packed.

[image: GAHangar]

And sailplanes can be lifted and hung from the ceiling for more space on the ground.

[image: SailHangar]